# Find and copy files to existing Folders with corresponding names in python

Tags: python

i have a large number of files that i need to move to a specific existing folder. the problem is that the number code that relates the file and the folder has text on either side of it as shown below the number code is a071137 in the file name and A071137 in the folder name.

for example, i need to move file: "a071137_gindalbie.pdf" to folder "A071137 2006 Teck Commginco  Pty Ltd" .

I would like to do this using python

I guess I first find the corresponding file using glob?
Then to copy it there ?? not sure??

Comment: Your example ""a071137_gindalbie.pdf" to folder "A73070 2006 Teck Commginco Pty Ltd"  does not make any sense. Where is the connection between both names??? Poor question...

Comment: Sorry that should have been""A73070_gindalbie.pdf" to folder "A73070 2006 Teck Commginco Pty Ltd" my appologies....

Comment: Well what is the question? Iterating the files first and then searching for their target directory or searching all matching files for a given target directory.....this is up to you...why should we decide that? Where is the *real* programming problem? At least we are not into making business logic decisions for you.

Comment: first find the file in a given dir based on the code A73070 for eg then find corresponding folder based on same code in another dir (already existing) and copy it to that dir

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't double post. If you want to revise your question, just click the 'edit' link.

Comment: sorry people new to programming and the site didn't mean to offend

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague, but hopefully I can at least point you in the right direction here. Sounds like you will want to be able to list all of the files in a directory, which can be done with `os.listdir(directory)` as described in the [api](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html). You will likely then iterate through these files, and extract the relevant information you will need using a regular expression. You'll need to reference [the api](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) on that too.  For example, you can extract a number using something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile('^a(?P<id>[0-9]+)')
>>> m = r.match('a123')
>>> m.group('id')
'123'
```

Next you can move files using things in the `shutil` module. You should be able to use `shutil.move()` for your purposes. For more information, again, checkout [the api](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html).